# I have an SSIS package with a SQL Task and a Data Flow Task and both are throwing connection errors

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask, execute-sql-task, ssis-connection-manager

I have a SSIS package that I am running in VS2015 for testing. I connect to 3 different databases on 2 different SQL instances (default and a named instance). Running SQL2019 Standard. Any connection to the default instance run just fine. Any connection to the named instance fails during execution. I dropped the original connection manager and created a new one and got the same errors. I tested the connection manager and it tests successfully.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzsie.png)

Named Instance (The one that fails):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRbWq.png)

Default Instance (The one that works):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMDmL.png)

I have a Execute SQL Task that fails with: [Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "PPro_ParagonImport". Connection may not be configured correctly, or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.
In Profiler, no connection is even made.

I have a Data Flow Task that fails with:
[OLE DB Source APG [68]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "PPro_ParagonImport" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: OLE DB Source APG failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
In Profiler I can see the connection and the SQL statement. The connection is made under my domain account.

I am sysadmin on both the Default and Named Instance.

I have been googling the error text and codes and cannot find anything that seems to work.
Any ideas or pointers would be greatly appreciated.